# How do I properly pass arguments over to the constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm working on an exercise in a beginner level C++ course, and I'm a bit stuck.

The directions as follows: 
Starting with the Account class in Fig. 3.4 of your textbook, add two additional data members (accountNumber and socialSecurityNumber) to the name data member that is already in the Account class. accountNumber should be of type int, and the socialSecurityNumber should be a string. Your class should have a constructor (with 3 parameters) that uses the parameters to initialize the 3 data members.

Add a set function for each of the two additional data members to pass data into the data members. Also, provide a get function for each data member to retrieve its value.

Write a test (driver) program similar to the program in Fig. 3.5 that demonstrates class Account’s capabilities as follows: 
- Create 3 Account objects by passing 3 appropriate arguments to the constructor when each object is created. 
- Display the values of accountNumber, socialSecurityNumber and name of each of the 3 Account objects.

Seems simple enough. As far as I understand the exercise, we don't have to have the user input data for their name, account number, and ssn. It's just hard coded. I think I've done alright creating the class, but passing over the arguments to the constructor when each object is created is making me pull my hair out. Would appreciate some assistance.

.h file:

```
// Fig. 3.4: Account.h
// Account class with a constructor that initializes the account name.
#include <string>

class Account {
public:
   // constructor initializes data member name with parameter accountName
    Account(std::string accountName, std::string SSN, int accountNumber) 
     : name{accountName}   { // member initializer

    void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber);
}               

// why can't I place this here? What does the green underline mean?
//void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber);


        //set function to set the account name
void setName(std::string accountName) {
    name = accountName;
}
        //set function to set the SSN
void setSSN(std::string SSN) {
    socialSecurityNumber = SSN;
}


                //GET FUNCTIONS
    //get function to retrieve the account name
   std::string getName() const {
  return name; 
} 


    //get function for data member accountNumber
  int getAccountNumber() const {
   return accountNumber;
  }

  //get function for data member socialSecurityNumber
   std::string getSSN() const {
   return socialSecurityNumber;
}


private:
   std::string name; // account name data member
   int accountNumber; //account number data member
   std::string socialSecurityNumber; // social security number data member
};
```

And the .cpp file:

```
// Fig. 3.5: AccountTest.cpp
// Using the Account constructor to initialize the name data
// member at the time each Account object is created.
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

int main() { 
//declaring data members
std::string name; // account name data member
int accountNumber; //account number data member
std::string socialSecurityNumber; // social security number data member

            // create three Account objects


   Account account2{"John Blue", 780909, "130099"}; 

   cout << "account2 name is: " << account2.getName();
   cout << "The account number for " << account2.getName() << " is " << 
account2.getAccountNumber();
   cout << "The social security number for " << account2.getName() << " is " << account2.getSSN();


   // the two lines needed so that my compiler doesn't immediately crash
   std::cin.ignore();
   std::cin.get();
 }
```

If I were to take out the "780909" and "130099" from within the object, and the code to display those numbers -- it works fine. It'll display John Blue just fine, but when I try to add those two series of numbers and the code to then display those numbers -- it won't work and I'm not sure why. Also for reference, those numbers are arbitrary and don't really mean anything. They could be any series of numbers.

As for the object being Account account2, I’m getting a red line underneath the farthest left brace that says (const char[10])”John Blue” No instance of constructor “Account::account” matches the argument list Argument types are: (const char[10], int, int). I'm not sure if that's of any help, but that's the compilation error that I'm getting.

EDIT2: I've gotten it to spit out some data. It correctly spits out the name of the account holder, John Blue, then it gives me the completely wrong number for the account number (it gives me -858993460 as the account number), and doesn't give me anything for the social security number. I'm not sure why it's not displaying the correct data.

Anyway, I'd appreciate any and all help.

Comment: You mentioned a green underline. What does it say when you mouse over it?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list.

Comment: When I mouse over it -- it says: 

void Account::setAccountNumber(int accountNumber)
Why can’t I place this here? What does that mean?

Function definition for ‘setAccountNumber’ not found. 

But when I have it within the body of the constructor, I get no errors. I'm not sure if I should be putting that line within the body of the constructor or not, but as of right now its not giving me any errors, so I haven't touched it.

Comment: One thing, "123" is a character string constant so it should not be passed to a function expecting an integer.  You need to remove the quotes.  foo("123") wrong, foo(123) right.  C++ has more strict typing of variables than JavaScript or PHP where they convert "1" <==> 1 for you silently as needed.  Also,  class and function declarations go in .h, class function definitions go in a cpp file and take the form classname::function-name( args ) {   }

Comment: As for the object, I’m getting a red line under ness the farthest left brace that says (const char[10])”John Blue”

No instance of constructor “Account::account” matches the argument list 


Argument types are: (const char[10], int, int) 

@chris

Comment: @DaveS I just caught that myself as you commented, and I deleted the quotes as you suggested. I totally forgot about that. As for the second portion of your comment, didn't I follow those rules with my code above? I'm fairly certain I've got the class and function declarations properly in the .h file, and function definitions in my .cpp file, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Sidenote: Even though account number is a number, they almost always have a particular format that doesn't allow you to ignore the leading zeros. You also rarely perform arithmetic on one. For these reasons you might be better off with `std::string accountNumber;`.

Comment: You need to close the constructor function before you start writing the setAccountNumber. That function should be within the class body.

Comment: I believe I've tried that already. I turned it into a comment so that I would remember what I wrote for reference to that question on line 13 there where I'm asking about the green line. If I take it out of the constructor I get a green line underneath "setAccountNumber". When I mouse over it I get: 

Function definition for ‘setAccountNumber’ not found.  ...But when I have it within the body of the constructor, I get no errors. I'm not saying that just because I'm getting no errors that it's correct, but yeah. I may be misinterpreting what you mean by closing the constructor though. @Imran

Comment: The data types in the constructor `std::string accountName, std::string SSN, int ssNumber` and the call don't match. `account2{"John Blue", 780909, 130099};`. Either SSN should be a numeric type or the constructor call should pass a string value.

Comment: @Imran So, I made the corrects as you suggested. However, the social security number is supposed to be of type string from the directions of the exercise. I don't have any errors in my object anymore. I can run the program, but it gives either missing or completely wrong data back. It'll display the account name just fine, it'll display the completely wrong number for the account number (that number is -858993460 for reference), and doesn't display anything for the social security number.

Comment: @Rob You need to change it in both the places to a string then. In the constructor call surround the number by double quotes e.g. `"123456"` .

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at a constructor *declares* a function within it's body

```
Account(std::string accountName, std::string SSN, int accountNumber) 
 : name{accountName}   { // member initializer

    void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber); // A declaration of a function
}
```

You shouldn't involve the setters in the constructor, but just intialise the other data members in the same way as `name`.

```
Account(std::string name, int number, std::string SSN) 
  : name(name), number(number), SSN(SSN)
{} // No extra work needed here

// ...

std::string name; // account name data member
int number;       // account number data member
std::string SSN;  // social security number data member
```

If you have no other constraints, it's a good idea to pass the constructor arguments in the same order as how the data members are declared. They will be initialised in declaration order, and not the order they appear in the initialiser list, so if those differ people can be confused.

Answer (score -1):

You are nearly there! You need to initialize all data members in your constructor (there are two ways to do so) and you need to call your constructor with arguments in the right order and with correct types.

I don't know how c++ reacts to class members and local function variables having identical names, but just for clarity/readability I would use different notations [NB: for sure there are coding guidelines out there suggesting other notation; use whatever you want or are required to use, but maintain readability anyway].

```
// Fig. 3.4: Account.h
// Account class with a constructor that initializes the account name.
#include <string>

class Account {
public:
   // constructor initializes data member name with parameter accountName, ...
    Account(std::string account_name, std::string ssn, int account_number) {

    setName(account_name);
    setAccountNumber(account_number);
    setSSN(ssn);
}               

void setAccountNumber(int account_number) {
     accountNumber = account_number;
}    

        //set function to set the account name
void setName(std::string account_name) {
    name = account_name;
}
        //set function to set the SSN
void setSSN(std::string ssn) {
    socialSecurityNumber = ssn;
}


                //GET FUNCTIONS
    //get function to retrieve the account name
   std::string getName() const {
  return name; 
} 


    //get function for data member accountNumber
  int getAccountNumber() const {
   return accountNumber;
  }

  //get function for data member socialSecurityNumber
   std::string getSSN() const {
   return socialSecurityNumber;
}


private:
   std::string name; // account name data member
   int accountNumber; //account number data member
   std::string socialSecurityNumber; // social security number data member
};
```

The alternative way to write your constructor would be:

```
Account(std::string account_name, std::string ssn, int account_number) 
  : name(account_name), socialSecurityNumber(ssn), accountNumber(account_number)
{
}
```

Finally, the constructor should be used with the parameters occurring in correct order:

```
Account alice("Alice","123abc",4711);
Account bob("Bob","x39",1234);
```

In your `main()` function you are declaring three variables that are not needed: `name`, `accountNumber`, `socialSecurityNumber`.

Comment: The "alternative" constructor should be the "primary"